# Git merge - changes missing

Tags: android, git, github, merge

I ran into a really annoying Git problem and don't know how to solve it. Hopefully you can give me a hint.

I have a child-branch of my master-branch. On that child-branch I made several changes. For instances adding methods to a class and so on. Later on I merged those changes into the master-branch. But I can't see them there. All changes are gone. And according to Git all changes of the child-branch are on the master.

So, do I need to manually do all changes again (on the master), or is there a way to force a merge of the child-branch onto the master again that really includes my source code changes?

PS: my code changes are still there when I checkout the child-branch. and they are also on the remote-origin of the child-branch.

Comment: Without knowing what specific Git commands you ran, the best we could do is speculate.  Please provide some more info!

Comment: I'm using Git Eclipse plugin and only Checkout and Merge via the context menu.

Comment: Navigate to your `.git/logs` folder and tell us what's in `refs/heads/{child}` and `refs/heads/{master}`.  It can be verbose, so try to include only the most recent handful of things you did with your repository.